# Where can I find login icons?

Tags: facebook, icons

Not a programming question as such but I'm wondering where I can find some large icons with 'Login with Facebook'

Comment: Not a programming question indeed. So it doesn't belong here. Try asking google maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the icons/images of the Facebook Application?
You need to go to : www.facebook.com/developers/, then find the application and click edit.
Upload 2 icons. One 16x16 and one 75x75.
If the application is Tab App, then you can upload a 111x74 image.

Answer (score 1):

look at iconwanted.com There are a lot of free icons, and also for forums. Also you can look for social icon sets.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the websites like this:

http://www.large-icons.com/stock-icons/free-social-media/facebook.htm 
http://blog.websitetemplates.bz/website_templates_news/facebook-icons.html